# Backbone collection: add logic to item models

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

I update a Backbone collection from array of bare objects by using `reset`:

```
const collection = new Backbone.Collection();
// ... 
const switches = [
    { color: "red", on: false },
    { color: "green", on: false },
    { color: "blue", on: true }
];
collection.reset(switches);
```

Now there are 3 models in my collection. I want them to have `toggle()` method:

```
toggle: function() { 
    this.save({ on: !this.get("on") }) 
}
```

How can I add it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you don't pass a model to a backbone collection, backbone uses normal models. If you want to have a customized models, you should define a model by using the `Backbone.Model.extend()` function and pass it to the collection:

```
const Model =  Backbone.Model.extend({
   toggle: function() { 
      this.save({ on: !this.get("on") }) 
   }
});
const Collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
   model: Model
});
const collection = new Collection();
```

Comment: I've updated the question replacing arrow function with normal. The value of `this` is not the issue, the question is not about that.